# Specifying colours in the form (r, g, b)?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I'm using

```
android:background="#rrggbb"
```

To specify colours. I now have to create a massive table with lots of background colours which I have in a list as rgb(238,130,238) etc.

Is it possible to use this instead of converting each number to hex?

Like:
    android:background="(238,130,238)"

Comment: No you can't. Only HEX is supported in XML.

Comment: Thanks. What a pity. Looks like I'll have to write a script to convert it.

Comment: A very difficult script, I suppose... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are specifying the color in the XML file, then you have to use a color hex string in the form of "#RRGGBB".

However, you can programmatically specify the red, green, and blue components as base-10 integers if you use the `View.setBackGroundColor(int color)` method. You can set the correct color like so:

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 130, 238));
```

Answer (score 0):

This `android:background="#rrggbb"`is an android tag and android framework parses this attribute `android:background` and always expect a hex value and converts to corresponding color. Its a standard and these standards should be followed.

If you want to convert it to custom (r,g,b) it is possible if you can edit android framework source code and compile it again to your needs.

Or as suggested above do it using java code.